# Using Import In NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

At the moment all my module in my nodejs server are imported as require() ie:

```
let path = require('path');
let express = require('express');
let http = require('http');
let app = express();
```

However the tutorial I am following shows them imported as:

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
```

Which throws the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

My webpack.config.js is set up as:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
}
```

In bablerc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

My package versions:

```
   "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",

   "react": "^15.0.1",

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "0.0.3",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.17.1"
  }
```

Import works in all my react components files, just not server.js. How do I switch my server over to Import from require?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It works in the webpack situation because the code is run through babel. You can run your node.js code through babel.

Install the babel cli if you don't have it

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Then run your code like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js
```

Or put it in package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node server.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand there is some discussion in the nodejs dev team about how to handle the import statement. It should be included in node at some point, but for now it's babel...

Comment: It's going to be pretty different from the way babel does it. I'll probably continue using babel's implementation for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Why do you install `babel-cli` to use `babel-node`? and your solution actually is not helping at all. Still the same error.

Comment: Now you can just place `"type": "module"` on you package JSON

Comment: how to use babel-node command when we have nodemon ?

Answer (score 5):

By default, you’ll be using ES5, and it’ll be required to use `require` to pull in modules. As we move forward with ES6 and beyond, it’s really best for us to start using ES6 classes as well as import and export statements. To do this, we’ll need Babel in order to interpret our ES6 syntax.

1. `npm install --save-dev babel-cli`
2. `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`
3. Let's pull in both *babel-cli* and *babel preset es2015* as dev dependencies as well as add the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

The issue should be gone, if you follow above steps

For more information please see: https://codebrains.io/setting-up-express-with-es6-and-babel/

Comment: any thoughts for nodemon ?

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2022:**

You can now use `"type": "module"` in your package.json file and this will enable the ES6 import. No **extra installations** needed.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "type": "module", 

  ...
}
```