# Electron error with Unexpected token import with import of express [Use of babel]

Tags: angular, express, electron, babel-loader

Please help me:

***I use electron,angular and an express server (Sequelize,Sqlite)***

Angular/Electron is from a github project by maxime gris:

```
  https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron
```

for my app server (classic express server):
     in api folder :|controller|helpers|models|routes

```
   /*server.js*/
    import express from 'express';
    import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
    import {getDb} from './helpers/dbHelper';
    import PirateModel from './models/pirateModel';
    import TypeModel from './models/typeModel';
    import PirateRouter from './routes/pirateRoutes';
    import TypeRouter from './routes/typeRoutes';

    const app = express();

    // connecting to sqlite database
    const db = getDb();

    // defining a model
    const Pirate = PirateModel(db);
    const Type = TypeModel(db);

    // syncing db to the model changes
    db.sync();

    // router
    const pirateRouter = PirateRouter(Pirate);
    const typeRouter = TypeRouter(Type);

    // parse request body as json
     app.use(express.json());

   // using the router at /api/pirates
    app.use('/api/pirates', pirateRouter);
    app.use('/api/types', typeRouter);

    app.listen(5000, () => console.log('App running on port 5000'));
```

in package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "glooglo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GlooGlo App",
  "homepage": "https://www.fakesite.net/",
  "author": {
    "name": "FakeName",
    "email": "fakeMail@fakesite.net"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular 6",
    "electron",
    "typescript",
    "sass"
  ],
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "start:server": "babel-node ./api/server.js",
    "build": "npm run electron:tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve -o",
    "electron:tsc": "tsc main.ts",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:tsc && npm run start:server && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && npm run start:server && electron -r babel-register .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.3",
    "save-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.10",
    "sqlite": "^2.9.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
    "timers": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "8.9.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.6",
    "electron": "2.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "20.14.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3",
    "electron-reload": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.3",
    "npx": "10.2.0",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "ts-node": "6.0.3",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "wait-on": "2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "retainLines": true
  }
}
```

In main.ts:

```
 import { app, BrowserWindow, screen } from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';

// import './api/server';  <= FOR TESTING I USE THIS

let win, serve;
const args = process.argv.slice(1);
serve = args.some(val => val === '--serve');

function createWindow() {

  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  const appPath = app.getAppPath();
  // WHEN I PACKAGE THE APP I USE THIS
  const serverLink = path.join(__dirname , '..' , './../api/server.js');
  const runServer = require(serverLink);
 // END WHEN I PACKAGE

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height
  });

  if (serve) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
     electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`)});
    win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');
  } else {
    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));
  }

  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store window
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });
}

try {

  // This method will be called when Electron has finished
  // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
  // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
  app.on('ready', createWindow);

  // Quit when all windows are closed.
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });

} catch (e) {
  // Catch Error
  // throw e;
}
```

In electron-builder.json:

```
{
  "productName": "IGLOO",
  "directories": {
    "output": "app-builds"
  },
    "files": [
        "**/*",
        "!*.ts",
        "!*.code-workspace",
        "!LICENSE.md",
        "!package.json",
        "!package-lock.json",
        "!src/",
        "!e2e/",
        "!hooks/",
        "!.angular-cli.json",
        "!_config.yml",
        "!karma.conf.js",
        "!tsconfig.json",
        "!tslint.json"
    ],
  "win": {
    "icon": "dist",
    "target": [
      "portable"
    ]
  },
  "mac": {
    "icon": "dist",
    "target": [
      "dmg"
    ]
  },
  "linux": {
    "icon": "dist",
    "target": [
      "AppImage"
    ]
  },
  "extraFiles":[
    "api",
    "database"
  ]
}
```

**THE PROBLEM?**
 when i run :

```
 npm run electron:local  => The App work correctly and the server too
```

Now when i package my app with:

```
  npm run electron:windows => I have the packaged app: Glooglo.exe (with api/database)
```

When i run this app:

```
    Uncaught Exception
     import express from 'express'
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    ......
   at App.createWindow
    at \app\ressoucers\app.asar\main.js:19.20
```

The babel preset with Es2015 does not work when i package the app and run it

Comment: could you post clearer code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Import In NodeJS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645548/using-import-in-nodejs-server)

Comment: I update my post for a clearer code.
pushkin this is not a duplicate because this is not the same .I use electron and i now that babel is necessary for the compile .It works when i test but not when i package my app