# Runing a server using import instead of require in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the following server code for a react app (created from create react app):

```
import config from './../config/config'
import app from './express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// Connection URL
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUri)
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
  throw new Error(`unable to connect to database: ${mongoUri}`)
})

app.listen(config.port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.info('Server started on port %s.', config.port)
})
```

The other server side files uses "Import" as well..

When trying to run it by `node server.js` I am getting the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import config from
 './../config/config'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How should I start my react app so the client side would run and also this server.js server from the begining ?, I would usually use the following in package.json:

```
 "dev": "concurrently \"npm run react\" \"npm run server\"",
 "react": "react-scripts start",
 "server": "node src/server/index.js",
```

But the node command won't work in this case. I tried this with no success:
[Using Import In NodeJS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645548/using-import-in-nodejs-server)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is because ESM (import/export) was introduced to Node in version 12. You have two options: if you are using node v12 or higher you can follow this [link](https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports).

If you are using a lower version of node you'll have to use babel to transpile your code. Check this [link](https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-node-js-babel-setup/).